# List Contains() with PLinq?

Tags: c#, .net, plinq, .net-4.0

let's say I have a big List

```
List<long> longList = new List<long>(10000000)
```

And I want to do the following query:

```
bool found = longList.Contains(4345235234524245124L);
```

Is there a way to use PLinq for that to let each thread search just a little part of the list?

I know that using a Dictionary or a HashMap would be better in this case. It is just something I want to know regarding PLinq and this example was very handy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yup, using

```
bool found = longList.AsParallel().Contains(4345235234524245124L);
```

should indeed parallelize it.